# display a android toast when sms is received

Tags: android

i want to display a simple `Toast` when `sms` is received. i am trying this from last 4 days still no success. please do help. 
 sometimes my app executes corectly. some times it does not.

1) when i create a new project with a blank `Activity` and add a `Button` to it. so that click on `Button` a `Toast` is shown.
------> execution of this is successfull. it works fine.
now

2) i delete `layout\*.xml` file and edit my `MainActivity.java` and `Manifest.xml` (as follows) it shows me the `Toast` when `sms` is received. 
BUT
if i recompile it and re-run it , same code and same `Manifest` (noting is changed) it does not work.

in short at 1st execution it works fine after that it never get executed.

MAINACTIVITY.JAVA

```
package com.example.vaibhav.savemev2;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class MainActivity extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(context,"SMS RECEIVED BRO !",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

MANIFEST.XML

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.vaibhav.savemev2">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
<application android:allowBackup="true" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <receiver android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
   </application>
 </manifest>
```

`LOGCAT`(NOTWORKING that is for the 2nd,3rd,4th...... time of compilation. point number 3)

```
04-13 00:18:25.542    1773-1773/com.google.process.gapps I/ConfigService﹕ onBind for Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.config.START pkg=com.google.android.gms } action com.google.android.gms.config.START
04-13 00:18:25.542    1773-1773/com.google.process.gapps I/ConfigService﹕ onBind returning service broker
04-13 00:18:25.578    1233-1245/system_process I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 29195(1867KB) AllocSpace objects, 9(144KB) LOS objects, 13% free, 10MB/11MB, paused 1.297ms total 2.026s
04-13 00:18:25.581    1233-1283/system_process I/art﹕ WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 810.831ms for cause Explicit
04-13 00:18:26.462    1233-1283/system_process I/art﹕ Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 5679(338KB) AllocSpace objects, 2(32KB) LOS objects, 16% free, 9MB/11MB, paused 9.483ms total 859.150ms
04-13 00:18:26.624    1973-1973/com.google.android.gms I/ConfigFetchService﹕ service connected
04-13 00:18:26.654    3531-3531/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
04-13 00:18:26.655    3531-3533/? I/art﹕ Debugger is no longer active
04-13 00:18:26.774    1233-1233/system_process D/BackupManagerService﹕ Received broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:com.example.vaibhav.savemev2 flg=0x4000010 (has extras) }
04-13 00:18:26.774    1233-1233/system_process W/BackupManagerService﹕ Removing schedule queue dupe of com.example.vaibhav.savemev2
04-13 00:18:26.809    1233-1269/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Resuming delayed broadcast
04-13 00:18:27.240    2038-2038/com.android.keychain W/ContextImpl﹕ Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.startService:1686 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:515 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:515 com.android.keychain.KeyChainBroadcastReceiver.onReceive:12 android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver:2579
04-13 00:18:27.245    1233-1472/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Delay finish: com.android.keychain/.KeyChainBroadcastReceiver
04-13 00:18:27.284    1233-1842/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Resuming delayed broadcast
04-13 00:18:27.311    1973-3551/com.google.android.gms D/PackageBroadcastService﹕ Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED and uri=com.example.vaibhav.savemev2
04-13 00:18:27.321    1233-1644/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Delay finish: com.google.android.gms/.app.receiver.SystemBroadcastReceiver
04-13 00:18:27.408    1973-1973/com.google.android.gms I/ConfigFetchService﹕ onStartCommand Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:com.example.vaibhav.savemev2 cmp=com.google.android.gms/.config.ConfigFetchService (has extras) }
04-13 00:18:27.409    1973-1973/com.google.android.gms I/ConfigFetchService﹕ launchTask
04-13 00:18:27.907    1973-3555/com.google.android.gms I/PeopleContactsSync﹕ CP2 sync disabled
04-13 00:18:27.908    1973-1973/com.google.android.gms I/ConfigFetchService﹕ service connected
04-13 00:18:27.967    1973-1973/com.google.android.gms D/ConfigFetchService﹕ ConfigApi connection successful.
04-13 00:18:28.035    1233-1272/system_process W/VoiceInteractionManagerService﹕ no available voice recognition services found for user 0
04-13 00:18:37.462    1973-3553/com.google.android.gms V/ConfigFetchTask﹕ ConfigFetchTask getDeviceDataVersionInfo(): ABFEt1V7na1GUYHmCFdhBRFSiefbF1ngJlylTaCxtj477EUPZ4tUkHtmCOqm3yL-4bmaZmZaWw7ipVyPnbnfUe04Mimqdod_MohZrTXZh15F1RAla6JoKLuzCufzRnkj505ZtfvnCb2Ayjzk2-YWKzcTP-vbOfgL2fW9mYnYwsv_wq_5Yqr92WCP2UViB4Ie7NhpJu8UBYCWd5R2DeVxdnZgJcHjB_p_9fLN2acfhJWXS0KMoDV1yxyzoPGC-ksM1zqMMpKC4JknD1ePU0EDyK_pjXVL1hxASE6GXtnLyVgS1eF2ik92lfZ8lDG-TYtFbkT__vJ1ANdkXdkCiNUxenPaOWezZf31LCE5H0kJ8pI8VSuC7pKxjVw
04-13 00:18:37.498    1973-3553/com.google.android.gms I/GoogleURLConnFactory﹕ Using platform SSLCertificateSocketFactory
04-13 00:18:37.807    1973-1973/com.google.android.gms I/ConfigFetchService﹕ fetch service done; releasing wakelock
04-13 00:18:37.808    1973-1973/com.google.android.gms I/ConfigFetchService﹕ stopping self
04-13 00:18:37.810    1233-1842/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Resuming delayed broadcast
04-13 00:18:37.856    1773-1773/com.google.process.gapps E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver﹕ Invalid parameter app
04-13 00:18:37.856    1773-1773/com.google.process.gapps E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver﹕ Invalid package name : Perhaps you didn't include a PendingIntent in the extras?
04-13 00:18:37.872    1233-1269/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Delay finish: com.google.android.gms/.gcm.nts.SchedulerReceiver
04-13 00:18:37.881    1233-1779/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Resuming delayed broadcast
04-13 00:18:37.886    1233-1339/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Delay finish: com.google.android.gms/.app.receiver.SystemBroadcastReceiver
04-13 00:18:37.888    1973-3558/com.google.android.gms D/PackageBroadcastService﹕ Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED and uri=com.example.vaibhav.savemev2
04-13 00:18:37.891    1973-3559/com.google.android.gms I/PeopleContactsSync﹕ CP2 sync disabled
04-13 00:18:37.925    1233-1580/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Resuming delayed broadcast
04-13 00:18:38.028    1233-1269/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Delay finish: com.android.mms/.transaction.PrivilegedSmsReceiver
04-13 00:18:38.031    2161-2161/com.android.mms V/Mms﹕ onStart: #1 mResultCode: -1 = Activity.RESULT_OK
04-13 00:18:38.489    2161-3560/com.android.mms D/Mms﹕ handleSmsReceived messageUri: content://sms/24 threadId: 1
04-13 00:18:38.522    2161-3560/com.android.mms D/Mms﹕ updateNotification: new message, adding sound to the notification
04-13 00:18:38.574    1233-1233/system_process I/ValidateNoPeople﹕ Validating: 0|com.android.mms|123|null|10010
04-13 00:18:38.575    1233-1233/system_process I/ValidateNoPeople﹕ final affinity: 0.0
04-13 00:18:38.592    1233-1268/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Resuming delayed broadcast
04-13 00:18:38.875    1415-3562/com.android.systemui E/MediaPlayer﹕ Should have subtitle controller already set
04-13 00:18:38.939    1233-1269/system_process I/MediaFocusControl﹕ AudioFocus  requestAudioFocus() from android.media.AudioManager@bfa2e69
04-13 00:18:38.941      944-944/? D/NuPlayerDriver﹕ start(0xb4883280)
04-13 00:18:38.942     944-1578/? D/NuPlayerDriver﹕ reset(0xb5a4b100)
04-13 00:18:38.948     944-3514/? D/NuPlayerDriver﹕ notifyResetComplete(0xb5a4b100)
04-13 00:18:38.948    1415-3562/com.android.systemui E/MediaPlayer﹕ Should have subtitle controller already set
04-13 00:18:38.949     944-3563/? I/GenericSource﹕ start
04-13 00:18:38.970     944-3565/? D/AudioSink﹕ bufferCount (8) is too small and increased to 12
04-13 00:18:40.975    1233-1472/system_process I/MediaFocusControl﹕ AudioFocus  abandonAudioFocus() from android.media.AudioManager@bfa2e69
04-13 00:18:41.422     944-1224/? I/AudioFlinger﹕ BUFFER TIMEOUT: remove(4097) from active list on thread 0xb61b7000
04-13 00:18:42.866    1773-1773/com.google.process.gapps I/ConfigService﹕ onDestroy
04-13 00:19:00.254    1415-1428/com.android.systemui I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 27578(1080KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 15% free, 6MB/7MB, paused 1.210ms total 193.993ms
04-13 00:19:22.023    3575-3575/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
04-13 00:19:22.075    3575-3575/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ CheckJNI is ON
04-13 00:19:23.256    3575-3575/? E/memtrack﹕ Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
04-13 00:19:23.257    3575-3575/? E/android.os.Debug﹕ failed to load memtrack module: -2
04-13 00:19:24.405    3575-3575/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
04-13 00:19:24.676    1781-3586/com.android.defcontainer D/DefContainer﹕ Copying /data/local/tmp/com.example.vaibhav.savemev2 to base.apk
04-13 00:19:24.767    1233-1283/system_process D/PackageManager﹕ Renaming /data/app/vmdl202891466.tmp to /data/app/com.example.vaibhav.savemev2-1
04-13 00:19:24.767    1233-1273/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Force stopping com.example.vaibhav.savemev2 appid=10059 user=-1: uninstall pkg
04-13 00:19:24.871    1233-1283/system_process I/PackageManager﹕ Package com.example.vaibhav.savemev2 codePath changed from /data/app/com.example.vaibhav.savemev2-2 to /data/app/com.example.vaibhav.savemev2-1; Retaining data and using new
04-13 00:19:24.871    1233-1283/system_process I/art﹕ DexFile_isDexOptNeeded failed to open oat file '/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.vaibhav.savemev2-1@base.apk@classes.dex' for file location '/data/app/com.example.vaibhav.savemev2-1/base.apk': Failed to open oat filename for reading: No such file or directory
04-13 00:19:24.874    1233-1283/system_process I/art﹕ DexFile_isDexOptNeeded failed to open oat file '/data/app/com.example.vaibhav.savemev2-1/x86/base.odex' for file location '/data/app/com.example.vaibhav.savemev2-1/base.apk': Failed to open oat filename for reading: No such file or directory
04-13 00:19:24.874    1233-1283/system_process I/PackageManager﹕ Running dexopt on: /data/app/com.example.vaibhav.savemev2-1/base.apk pkg=com.example.vaibhav.savemev2 isa=x86 vmSafeMode=false
04-13 00:19:25.221    3588-3588/? I/dex2oat﹕ /system/bin/dex2oat --zip-fd=6 --zip-location=/data/app/com.example.vaibhav.savemev2-1/base.apk --oat-fd=7 --oat-location=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.vaibhav.savemev2-1@base.apk@classes.dex --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m
04-13 00:19:25.844    3588-3588/? W/dex2oat﹕ Compilation of void com.example.vaibhav.savemev2.BuildConfig.<init>() took 166.920ms
04-13 00:19:25.874    3588-3588/? I/dex2oat﹕ dex2oat took 602.641ms (threads: 1)
04-13 00:19:25.875    1233-1273/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Force stopping com.example.vaibhav.savemev2 appid=10059 user=-1: update pkg
04-13 00:19:25.876    1233-1283/system_process W/PackageManager﹕ Code path for pkg : com.example.vaibhav.savemev2 changing from /data/app/com.example.vaibhav.savemev2-2 to /data/app/com.example.vaibhav.savemev2-1
04-13 00:19:25.876    1233-1283/system_process W/PackageManager﹕ Resource path for pkg : com.example.vaibhav.savemev2 changing from /data/app/com.example.vaibhav.savemev2-2 to /data/app/com.example.vaibhav.savemev2-1
04-13 00:19:25.929    1233-1283/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Force stopping com.example.vaibhav.savemev2 appid=10059 user=0: pkg removed
04-13 00:19:25.942    1233-1233/system_process D/BackupManagerService﹕ Received broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED dat=package:com.example.vaibhav.savemev2 flg=0x4000010 (has extras) }
04-13 00:19:25.942    1233-1233/system_process D/JobSchedulerService﹕ Receieved: android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED
04-13 00:19:25.982    1233-1283/system_process W/Settings﹕ Setting install_non_market_apps has moved from android.provider.Settings.Global to android.provider.Settings.Secure, returning read-only value.
04-13 00:19:25.992    1773-1773/com.google.process.gapps E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver﹕ Invalid parameter app
04-13 00:19:25.992    1773-1773/com.google.process.gapps E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver﹕ Invalid package name : Perhaps you didn't include a PendingIntent in the extras?
04-13 00:19:26.000    1233-1269/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Delay finish: com.google.android.gms/.app.receiver.SystemBroadcastReceiver
04-13 00:19:26.005    1973-3590/com.google.android.gms D/PackageBroadcastService﹕ Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED and uri=com.example.vaibhav.savemev2
04-13 00:19:26.011    1773-1773/com.google.process.gapps I/ConfigService﹕ onCreate
04-13 00:19:26.023    1773-1773/com.google.process.gapps I/ConfigService﹕ onBind for Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.config.UPDATE pkg=com.google.android.gms } action com.google.android.gms.config.UPDATE
04-13 00:19:26.027    1973-1973/com.google.android.gms I/ConfigFetchService﹕ onStartCommand Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED dat=package:com.example.vaibhav.savemev2 cmp=com.google.android.gms/.config.ConfigFetchService (has extras) }
04-13 00:19:26.052    1233-1320/system_process I/InputReader﹕ Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000010
04-13 00:19:26.056    1233-1320/system_process I/InputReader﹕ Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000010
04-13 00:19:26.061    1233-1233/system_process D/BackupManagerService﹕ Received broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:com.example.vaibhav.savemev2 flg=0x4000010 (has extras) }
04-13 00:19:26.061    1233-1233/system_process W/BackupManagerService﹕ Removing schedule queue dupe of com.example.vaibhav.savemev2
04-13 00:19:26.064    1233-1320/system_process I/InputReader﹕ Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000010
04-13 00:19:26.699    1511-1532/com.android.phone I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 8436(428KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 22% free, 1850KB/2MB, paused 1.184ms total 710.008ms
04-13 00:19:26.741    1773-1773/com.google.process.gapps I/ConfigService﹕ onBind returning update interface
04-13 00:19:26.743    1773-1773/com.google.process.gapps I/ConfigService﹕ onBind for Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.config.START pkg=com.google.android.gms } action com.google.android.gms.config.START
04-13 00:19:26.744    1773-1773/com.google.process.gapps I/ConfigService﹕ onBind returning service broker
04-13 00:19:26.801    1233-1272/system_process W/VoiceInteractionManagerService﹕ no available voice recognition services found for user 0
04-13 00:19:26.811    1233-1582/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Resuming delayed broadcast
04-13 00:19:26.834    2038-2038/com.android.keychain W/ContextImpl﹕ Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.startService:1686 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:515 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:515 com.android.keychain.KeyChainBroadcastReceiver.onReceive:12 android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver:2579
04-13 00:19:26.851    1233-1580/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Delay finish: com.android.keychain/.KeyChainBroadcastReceiver
04-13 00:19:26.954    1233-1269/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Resuming delayed broadcast
04-13 00:19:27.139    1233-1283/system_process I/art﹕ Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 24509(1676KB) AllocSpace objects, 10(160KB) LOS objects, 16% free, 9MB/11MB, paused 17.625ms total 1.041s
04-13 00:19:27.335    3575-3575/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
04-13 00:19:27.509    3575-3577/? I/art﹕ Debugger is no longer active
04-13 00:19:27.880    1233-1269/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Delay finish: com.google.android.gms/.app.receiver.SystemBroadcastReceiver
04-13 00:19:27.885    1973-3595/com.google.android.gms D/PackageBroadcastService﹕ Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED and uri=com.example.vaibhav.savemev2
04-13 00:19:27.898    1973-1973/com.google.android.gms I/ConfigFetchService﹕ onStartCommand Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:com.example.vaibhav.savemev2 cmp=com.google.android.gms/.config.ConfigFetchService (has extras) }
04-13 00:19:27.918    1973-1973/com.google.android.gms I/ConfigFetchService﹕ launchTask
04-13 00:19:28.234    1973-1973/com.google.android.gms I/ConfigFetchService﹕ service connected
04-13 00:19:28.238    1973-3599/com.google.android.gms I/PeopleContactsSync﹕ CP2 sync disabled
04-13 00:19:28.263    1973-1973/com.google.android.gms D/ConfigFetchService﹕ ConfigApi connection successful.
04-13 00:19:29.514    1773-1799/com.google.process.gapps E/StrictMode﹕ A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
    java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'end' not called
            at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
            at java.util.zip.Inflater.<init>(Inflater.java:82)
            at com.android.okio.GzipSource.<init>(GzipSource.java:57)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.initContentStream(HttpEngine.java:478)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:668)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:379)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:323)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:491)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:105)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
            at com.google.android.gms.http.GoogleHttpClient.a(SourceFile:791)
            at com.google.android.gms.http.GoogleHttpClient.b(SourceFile:760)
            at com.google.android.gms.http.GoogleHttpClient.execute(SourceFile:663)
            at com.google.android.gms.http.GoogleHttpClient.execute(SourceFile:654)
            at com.google.android.gms.playlog.uploader.e.a(SourceFile:346)
            at com.google.android.gms.playlog.uploader.e.a(SourceFile:232)
            at com.google.android.gms.playlog.uploader.e.a(SourceFile:204)
            at com.google.android.gms.playlog.uploader.UploaderService.a(SourceFile:52)
            at com.google.android.gms.gcm.ap.run(SourceFile:131)
04-13 00:19:37.973    1973-3597/com.google.android.gms V/ConfigFetchTask﹕ ConfigFetchTask getDeviceDataVersionInfo(): ABFEt1V7na1GUYHmCFdhBRFSiefbF1ngJlylTaCxtj477EUPZ4tUkHtmCOqm3yL-4bmaZmZaWw7ipVyPnbnfUe04Mimqdod_MohZrTXZh15F1RAla6JoKLuzCufzRnkj505ZtfvnCb2Ayjzk2-YWKzcTP-vbOfgL2fW9mYnYwsv_wq_5Yqr92WCP2UViB4Ie7NhpJu8UBYCWd5R2DeVxdnZgJcHjB_p_9fLN2acfhJWXS0KMoDV1yxyzoPGC-ksM1zqMMpKC4JknD1ePU0EDyK_pjXVL1hxASE6GXtnLyVgS1eF2ik92lfZ8lDG-TYtFbkT__vJ1ANdkXdkCiNUxenPaOWezZf31LCE5H0kJ8pI8VSuC7pKxjVw
04-13 00:19:37.977    1973-3597/com.google.android.gms I/GoogleURLConnFactory﹕ Using platform SSLCertificateSocketFactory
04-13 00:19:38.251    1973-1973/com.google.android.gms I/ConfigFetchService﹕ fetch service done; releasing wakelock
04-13 00:19:38.262    1973-1973/com.google.android.gms I/ConfigFetchService﹕ stopping self
04-13 00:19:38.265    1233-1842/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Resuming delayed broadcast
04-13 00:19:38.303    1773-1773/com.google.process.gapps E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver﹕ Invalid parameter app
04-13 00:19:38.303    1773-1773/com.google.process.gapps E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver﹕ Invalid package name : Perhaps you didn't include a PendingIntent in the extras?
04-13 00:19:38.322    1233-1779/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Delay finish: com.google.android.gms/.gcm.nts.SchedulerReceiver
04-13 00:19:38.329    1233-1644/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Resuming delayed broadcast
04-13 00:19:38.335    1973-3606/com.google.android.gms D/PackageBroadcastService﹕ Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED and uri=com.example.vaibhav.savemev2
04-13 00:19:38.335    1233-1580/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Delay finish: com.google.android.gms/.app.receiver.SystemBroadcastReceiver
04-13 00:19:38.340    1973-3607/com.google.android.gms I/PeopleContactsSync﹕ CP2 sync disabled
04-13 00:19:38.350    1233-1629/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Resuming delayed broadcast
04-13 00:19:43.329    1773-1773/com.google.process.gapps I/ConfigService﹕ onDestroy
04-13 00:20:12.317    1233-1580/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Delay finish: com.android.mms/.transaction.PrivilegedSmsReceiver
04-13 00:20:12.322    2161-2161/com.android.mms V/Mms﹕ onStart: #1 mResultCode: -1 = Activity.RESULT_OK
04-13 00:20:12.416    2161-3608/com.android.mms D/Mms﹕ handleSmsReceived messageUri: content://sms/25 threadId: 1
04-13 00:20:12.428    2161-3608/com.android.mms D/Mms﹕ updateNotification: new message, adding sound to the notification
04-13 00:20:12.434    1233-1233/system_process I/ValidateNoPeople﹕ Validating: 0|com.android.mms|123|null|10010
04-13 00:20:12.434    1233-1233/system_process I/ValidateNoPeople﹕ final affinity: 0.0
04-13 00:20:12.458    1415-3610/com.android.systemui E/MediaPlayer﹕ Should have subtitle controller already set
04-13 00:20:12.461    1233-1339/system_process I/MediaFocusControl﹕ AudioFocus  requestAudioFocus() from android.media.AudioManager@21dff0ee
04-13 00:20:12.462     944-1578/? D/NuPlayerDriver﹕ start(0xb5a4b1c0)
04-13 00:20:12.464     944-1226/? D/NuPlayerDriver﹕ reset(0xb4883280)
04-13 00:20:12.470     944-3563/? D/NuPlayerDriver﹕ notifyResetComplete(0xb4883280)
04-13 00:20:12.471    1415-3610/com.android.systemui E/MediaPlayer﹕ Should have subtitle controller already set
04-13 00:20:12.472     944-3611/? I/GenericSource﹕ start
04-13 00:20:12.491     944-3613/? D/AudioSink﹕ bufferCount (8) is too small and increased to 12
04-13 00:20:12.565    1233-1269/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Resuming delayed broadcast
04-13 00:20:14.485    1233-1580/system_process I/MediaFocusControl﹕ AudioFocus  abandonAudioFocus() from android.media.AudioManager@21dff0ee
04-13 00:20:14.933     944-1224/? I/AudioFlinger﹕ BUFFER TIMEOUT: remove(4097) from active list on thread 0xb61b7000
```

`LOGCAT`(WORKING, that is for the first time of compilation. point number 2)

https://www.dropbox.com/s/c7nlfh6qy4vg99m/workingLOGCAT.png?dl=0

Comment: it will be a great help if anyone mail me the working android studio project for displaying toast when sms is received with maximum sdk  as lolipop as i am using a lolipop os mobile..... please :-( my email id is vkvk24081993 [at the rate] gmail.com

Comment: Nobody will make an app for you here at Stack Overflow

Comment: At least add filtered logs.

Comment: i guess many of them are stuck over here. so i said to post the android studio project. if possible

Answer (score 0):

it's dizzy logcat......

I think duplication broadcastreceiver.

if you want to run every time after first running, register broadcastreceiver in back service, and unregisterReceiver if you want.

or you want to run at show activity, register broadcastreceiver and shutdown activity unregisterReceiver.

my english bad..... 
i hope help you.

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
    registerReceiver(smsreceiver, intentFilter);

if(smsreceiver != null){
        unregisterReceiver(smsreceiver);
        smsreceiver = null;
    }
```

thank you.

Comment: `registerReceiver(receiver, filter);` put when you start application or other you want to start receive. if you want back service, put service code.
'unregisterReceiver(receiver)` put when you want to stop.